# Ajax Call to mvc controller action is very slow when SignalR is fetching data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

**My App Flow**

In my App - Dashboard,

1. I have the SignalR scripts included which fetches new data as and when new data  arrives from the device
2. It also has ajax script that hits on the Controller to fetch data from the back end - when a Get button is clicked.

Ajax Call mentioned in #2 above takes more than 2 minutes if new data keeps getting in (i.e when SignalR is continuously fetching data and publishing to all connected clients).

Else

the Ajax Call Point#2 above takes very less time to get the data.

Any ideas, better way, ... on how I can avoid the slowness in the ajax call #2 even if SignalR continuously fetches data.

This is my #2 Ajax Call ==> Call to the `Home` Controller Action Method `SignalList`

```
 $('#DeviceID').on('change', function () {
    $('#DeviceName').text("Device : " + $('#DeviceID option:selected').text());
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SignalList",
        type: "POST",
        data: { deviceID: $('#DeviceID').val() },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        //cache: false,
        //async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            //alert("AAA");
            $('#signalCheckListBox').html(result);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

This is SignalR script

```
 (function () {   
// Defining a connection to the server hub.
var signalHub = $.connection.signalHub; //alert("ACCC");
// Setting logging to true so that we can see whats happening in the browser console log. [OPTIONAL]
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
// Start the hub
$.connection.hub.start();


// This is the client method which is being called inside the SignalHub constructor method every 3 seconds
signalHub.client.SendSignalData = function (signalData) {
    dModel = signalData;

    updateSignalData(signalData);//<============ # Statekemnt A 
};
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
}); }());
```

The **statement A** marked above is a method which (1)updates different html elements  in the UI and also (2)sends an email on a condition.
For sending the email too it hits the same controller `Home` (??? ***Would that be the problem???***)

The email ajax call is below ==> Its a call to `Home` Controller Action Method `Communicate`

```
function email(alarmSignalInfo) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Communicate",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //data: { alarmSignalInfo: JSON.stringify(alarmSignalInfo) },
    data: { alarmSignalInfo: alarmSignalInfo },
    //cache: false,
    //async: true,
    success: function (result) { onSuccess(result); }
}); }
```

Comment: Depends also on what you have in controller Home

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml  I didn't exactly get on what you are referring to.

Comment: What that you expect on controller that could make things go bad\slow

Comment: in the action Communicate you should have to code the gets data from db if that is slow the call to that is slow also

Comment: To hit Communicate or  /Home/SignalList it takes a lot of time- more than a minute sometime. The code within both methods (Communicate and SignalList) are really fast fetch.____ So the problem now is Ajax call is very slow

Comment: can you provide a working example that we can test?

Comment: All the jQuerys in the my Controller are already here and moreover I feel it has nothing much  to do with my code ___ the issue -slowness happens when signalR script is continuously fetching data from backend -as per my observation. Else its not slow but normal & code absolutely working fine. ___`My query is if any tuning required on Ajax calls when they are many & continuously active`.